# How to divide one column into several columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one column which I want to divide  into three columns

```
Name
Jack,Jon Man
```

to be like

```
first_name  , middle_name , last_name
jack        , Jon         , Man
```

The first name is followed by a comma and the middle name is followed by space.

Comment: What are the qualifications for splitting?  Creating new columns on the same or separate table are simple enough, but how do you want to split them?

Comment: can you show more name in your sample table?

Comment: actually i can divide the column depend on the first name followed by semi coma and the middle name followed by space, here what i mean.
jack,Jan Man

Comment: This is only possible if you have a delimiter such as comma, space , pipe etc..

Comment: you can have a name consisting of comma after firstname and space after middle name?so if jack,jon man is the name, you want assign the first, middle and last to different columns?

Comment: Parsing names is always fraught with issues.  i.e. in your example, how are you to know that is not a two word last name? First analyze your data carefully and build a test set that contains EVERY possible combination of different types of data you have, meaning muti-word first names, NULL middle names, mutil-part last names, last names with single quotes in them, etc.  Then add conditions that you don't have but may occur. Define rules for how to determine when you have a NULL middle name VS a two part last name, etc, only then start working on a solution. Make sure NULLS are handled!

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do with the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303).

This query identifies the first, second and third occurrence of alphabetical characters.  Provided there is a delimiter it doesn't matter what it is.

```
SQL> select col1 
  2         , regexp_substr(col1, '[[:alpha:]]+') first_name 
  3         , regexp_substr(col1, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 2) middle_name 
  4         , regexp_substr(col1, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 3) last_name 
  5  from t34;

COL1                           FIRST_NAME MIDDLE_NAM LAST_NAME
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
Jack,Jon Man                   Jack       Jon        Man

SQL>
```

Comment: Returns incorrect result for double first names ie: "John Jack,Jon Man". But otherwise learned something from it.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
name
---------
Jack,Jon Man
Dave,Mike Doe
Chris,Brad Duke
```

Query:

```
select substr(name, 0, instr(name, ',')-1) as first_name,
    substr(name, instr(name,',',1,1)+1, instr(name, ',')-1) as middle_name,
    substr(name, instr(name,' ',1,1), instr(name, ' ')+10) as last_name
from sample_data
```

Output:

```
first_name    middle_name    last_name
---------------------------------------
Jack          Jon            Man
Dave          Mike           Doe
Chris         Brad           Duke
```

Answer (score -2):

If we are just selecting the data, it can be done using simple substring functions.
For instance

```
 create table #Random
(
Name Varchar(50)
)
insert into #random values ('Jack,Jon Man')

select substring(Name,1,4)'First_Name', 
  substring(Name,6,3)'Middle_Name',
  substring(Name,10,3)'Last_Name'
from #Random
```

Comment: This solution only works for names of specific lengths and offsets.  Can you generalize it to parse 'Albert,Jack Solomon'?

Comment: I'm afraid this solution is too specific to this exact data.  What about two-part first names and last names?  NULL middle names?  Last names with single quotes in them, etc?  The solution needs to be flexible so it can handle any name thrown at it.

Comment: this solution works if the names totally have specific length.