# How to remove the space in character field?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column contains full name, some end users make a wrong entry like space, I would to remove the space from the records but I would only remove space from the first three characters.

Here is an example

```
Full_NAME  
-------------------  
J ON,JACK EDWARD
Al mond,abbe abbas
```

I want the result to be:

```
Full_NAME
------------------        
JON,JACK EDWARD
ALmond,abbe abbas
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex to replace the first space in the string will work with the data you posted:

```
SQL> select full_name,
  2         regexp_replace(full_name, '\s+', null, 1, 1) as cleaned_name
  3  from t67
  4  /

FULL_NAME          CLEANED_NAME
------------------ ------------------
J ON,JACK EDWARD   JON,JACK EDWARD
Al mond,abbe abbas Almond,abbe abbas

SQL>
```

However, the outcome is less happy when the leading element contains spaces in more than one place or no spaces at all:

```
SQL> select full_name,
  2         regexp_replace(full_name, '\s+', null, 1, 1) as cleaned_name
  3  from t67
  4  /

FULL_NAME          CLEANED_NAME
------------------ ------------------
J O N,JACK EDWARD  JO N,JACK EDWARD
J  ON,JACK EDWARD  JON,JACK EDWARD
Almond,abbe abbas  Almond,abbeabbas

SQL>
```

I guess this is related [to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431507/146325), and you need to retain the final space because it is a delimiter.  It is pretty tricky to cleanse data when the raw data uses common characters as delimiters, and even worse use more than one delimiter in the same string.

My advice is to use the output from my previous answer to split the string into three elements and apply subsequent cleansing to each element.  That way you can forget about the delimiting characters muddying the cleansing process.

The alternative is some really gnarly regex :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the NULLIF function here:

```
SELECT NULLIF(SUBSTR(FULLNAME, 1, 1), ' ') ||
         NULLIF(SUBSTR(FULLNAME, 2, 1), ' ') ||
         NULLIF(SUBSTR(FULLNAME, 3, 1), ' ') ||
         SUBSTR(FULLNAME, 4) AS CLEANED_NAME
  FROM T67;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c334/3)

Best of luck.